# Is it possible to create a list of tests to run in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

In Visual Studio each test and class with tests has an icon next to it that opens a dropdown to either run the tests, debug the tests or add them to a new test session. IntelliJ IDEA only has the options to run the tests or debug the tests.

Is there any way to create a list of tests from potentially disparate parts of the test suite then run them all in one go?

I'm using Junit 4 and if there's a plugin to do this, that would be satisfactory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right click on a package (and/or a selection of packages) and then choose `Run` or `Debug` from the context menu.

Here's a screenshot showing that in action:

[image]

The resulting `Run Configuration` is then available via `Run > Edit Configurations` where you can edit/add/remove packages/classes from the selected pattern ...

[image]

You could also create a JUnit suite or category and let it contain your 'tests of interest' and then run it via IntelliJ's JUnit runner.

Comment: I suppose that'll have to do. I was really hoping there was a more user friendly way than editing the configurations but I think you're right that there aren't. Thanks much, accepted.

Comment: The fact that you can [save the edited configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-saving-temporary-run-debug-configurations.html#saveTempConfiguration) might help ease the pain :)